# How to solve "The Login Failed" error (JDBC Java) when only fails in one of two cases having Windows Authentication

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have Java code that uses JDBC for the connection to two databases of my company. The administrator gave me both permissions as *Windows autentication*. I can connect and interact to **both** databases with SQL Server Managment Studio perfectly. The problem is that I can work only with the first database with JDBC in java because trying to connect to the second database it results in a *"cannot open database"* error.

It is strange because I can work with the first database perfectly and the main server of both databases is the same. I have the JDBC drivers and the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file required for Windows authentication. I used modularized methods to avoid type mistakes. Here is the code (I changed some chars in XXX for security reasons):

```
package Auto;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test7 
{

    private final static int PORT = 1441;

    /**
     * This is the method that executes the connections
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            // === Correct connection with server 1 === //
            String server1Name = "XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\\XXXXDCESQL";
            String databaseName1 = "FacturaElectronicav2";

            String urlServer1 = getURLforconnection(server1Name, databaseName1);
            Connection conn1 = startSQLconnection(urlServer1);

            String table = "dbo.UsersExternal";
            String searcher = "Email";
            String searcherValue = "User@gmail.com";
            String column = "TokenCode";

            String dato = obtainValueFromStatement(conn1, table, searcher, searcherValue, column);

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("URL connection: " + urlServer1);
            System.out.println("The conenction was created succesful because this was printed");
            System.out.println("Value: " + dato + " // The value obtained from the statement is correct");
            System.out.println("");

            closeSQLConnection(conn1);

            System.out.println("Here goes the connection failure in the second database");
            System.out.println("");

            // === SECOND DATABASE=== //
            String server2Name = "XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\\XXXXDSSINTSQL";
            String databaseName2 = "SISECPrueba";

            String urlServer2 = getURLforconnection(server2Name, databaseName2);

            // Here the connection fails
            Connection conn2 = startSQLconnection(urlServer2);
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // Here the catch handles the exception while trying to connect to the second database
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the url for the connection to the database
     * It uses Windows Authentication [integratedSecurity=true]
     * @param serverName Name of the server connection
     * @param databaseName Name of the database of the server
     * @return The url for the JDBC connection
     */
    public String getURLforconnection(String serverName, String databaseName)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverName+":"+PORT+";databaseName="+databaseName+";integratedSecurity=true";
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the connection with the database
     * @param URL URL for the JDBC connection
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Connection startSQLconnection(String URL) throws Exception
    {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        return conn;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the connection with the database
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void closeSQLConnection(Connection Con) throws Exception
    {
        Con.close();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value searched in the database by the parameters
     * @param Table Table where the value is
     * @param Searcher Identifier of the search
     * @param SearcherValue Value of the identifier
     * @param Column Column of the table
     * @return The value of the statement
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String obtainValueFromStatement(Connection Con, String Table, String Searcher, String SearcherValue, String Column) throws Exception
    {
        String answer = "";

        String SQLstatement = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + Searcher + " = '" + SearcherValue + "'";
        Statement statement = Con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQLstatement);

        if(rs.next()) { answer = rs.getString(Column); }
        else { throw new Exception("It can not be found a registry in the statement"); }

        statement.close();
        rs.close();

        return answer;
    }

}
```

The expected result is a correct connection to both databases. However, only the first connection is successful and the value obtained from the table of the database is printed while the second fails as shown in the console output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite

URL connection: jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\XXXXDCESQL:1441;databaseName=FacturaElectronicav2;integratedSecurity=true
The conenction was created succesful because this was printed
Value: 1CE9AAB6-DEC4-481F-81E9-45DAB1D018CC // The value obtained from the statement is correct

Here goes the connection failure in the second database

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "SISECPrueba" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:d122e604-a8e2-4fa7-b1dc-aec3f6e6d9fd
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:213)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2242)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2228)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5574)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1734)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1355)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1022)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:858)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at Auto.Test7.startSQLconnection(Test7.java:86)
        at Auto.Test7.test(Test7.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
```

The problem appears to be the connection to the specific database SISECPrueba of the second server because the server instance is correct.

Finally, as I mentioned before, I have normal access to both servers with the windows application SQL Server Managment Studio.

Comment: Try to modify the method `public Connection startSQLconnection(String URL) throws Exception
{
 return DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
}` and save the connection to different variables; `connection1` and `connection2`

Comment: _"the main server of both databases is the same"_, that is not really relevant: they are two different SQL Server instances, that can have different configuration. The fact they are hosted on the same machine does not change the fact that these are two different SQL Servers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the clarification :D

Comment: @Max, I did what you suggested but sadly it did not work :(, the error remains the same. I upgrade the code above in the question. practically the code is the same.

Comment: The two SQL Server **Service** users are the same ? If you reverse the order of connection the result is the same ?

Comment: @Max, Sorry I do not know if the Service users are the same, how can I know that? Second, if I reverse the order the result is the same :(

Comment: Connect to the SISECPrueba with Sql Server Management Studio and open the logs under Management->SQL Server Logs to find more clues. For the service users: open the services, right click over the SQL Server instance: properties->Logon tab